# VS Code not running a Python file in the conda environment mentioned

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I have both anaconda and VS Code installed in my system. When I start writing a script, VS Code gives me an option to chose the interpreter. I choose my particular conda environment. This works fine. However when I try to run the script using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or using the play button on the top right (using the extension **Code Runner**), the terminal that opens in the VS Code doesn't recognize that I am now working in a conda environment.

As a result, it gives an error that the module is not installed (because the module is available only in the conda environment).

When I try to manually activate the conda environment from the VS Code terminal, it doesn't work.

What is the workaround? I am using Windows.

Update: If I use `cmd` as the default integrated terminal in VS Code in place of `PowerShell`, then the command `activate NAME_OF_ANACONDA_ENV` works. And then, I can manually run the script. However, running the script using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> still doesn't work; it doesn't recognize that I am in a conda env.

Comment: This seems like a problem with the Code Runner extension, you might want to report it over there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On windows 10: `Ctrl+Shift+P` and selecting the environment gets the job done. 
After setting the environment, I execute by pressing `Crtl+F5` to execute without debugging and `F5` to debug.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, this does not work. With this I am able to select the interpreter for the project. **However when I run the script, it doesn't remember the interpreter and  doesn't run in the environment I selected**

Comment: What do you see, when you press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and write `Python: Select Interpreter`, and does the result change if you use the conda environment here?

Comment: I am able to change to the desired environment in this way. So for example, if there is a module called `a` in my environment, `import a` is not underlined in red. However, when I run using the CodeRunner extension, it says `module a does not exist` clearly meaning, that CodeRunner is not recognizing that I am in a conda environment.

Comment: I guess it is the extension. I am using https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python Could you please give it a try?

Answer (score 7):

After a few tries i figured out how to do it. So, this works for me.

1. vs code settings search: `code-runner.executorMap`
2. Choose `User` and
   `Edit in settings.json`
3. find:    `"python": "python -u"`
4. change:  `"python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName"`

if you encounter `tempCodeRunnerFile` or selection problem:

1. vs code settings search: `code-runner.ignoreSelection`
2. tick the box

Comment: I encountered `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ...` for some modules, but I guess that's another problem then